# tselect doesn't work in vim+cscope

Tags: linux, vim, kernel, cscope

I use make cscope in Linux kernel to generate the cscope.out, and in vim I can use ctrl-] to jump among function defines. But if I use `:tselect` to display all function defines, vim report

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found:
```

and also when I use `:tnext` to get to the last tag, it will report the same error.

I use linux mint 13 64bit, vim and cscope are all installed by apt from offical repository.

Answer (score 0):

ctags and cscope are two different things and handled differently in vim.  ':tselect', the ctags-way to jump to a function, won't work on a cscope database.  Instead, you want to use

```
:cstag
```

The vim help system has a nice collection of advice:

```
:help cscope-suggestions
```

Comment: thanks your reply, I already have the settings in :help cscope-suggestions added in my .vimrc, and those <C-\>s g c... seems working in my vim, but I don't find any instructions to replace :tselect :tnext and :tprev, which are very useful when there are multi find results.

Comment: those commands are definitely useful.  With the 'cscopetag' option set, my vim session appears to use the cscope database when using :tselect :tnext and :tprev

Comment: I have done the `set cscopetag` in .vimrc, so this just doesn't work in my vim...